# About the proof of Alexandroff Compactification Theorem

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the Alexandroff compactification using Schubert's book. As far as I understand, the Alexandroff theorem can be stated as follows:

> **Theorem:**(Alexandroff compactification) *Let X
>     be a locally compact space. Then, there exists a compact space $X^{*}$
>     such that $X$
>     is homeomorphic to a subspace $A$
>     of $X^{*}$
>     and $X^{*}-A=\{w\}$
>     (with $w$
>     a point of $X^{*}$
>    ). Also, $X^{*}$
>     is uniquely determined up to homeomorphism.*

On the very first line of the proof, Schubert writes the following:

> The set $X^*$ consists of the set $X$ and another point $w$.

I really don't get why he writes this: shouldn't it be $X^*=A\cup \{w\}$?

Comment: If you're exact you should say $X^\ast = X \cup \{w\}$, where $w \notin X$.Twice using $X$ reflects the idea that we want $X$ as the original space and $X$ as a subspace of a new space $X^\ast$ (to be defined) to be homeomorphic, using the identity in fact. Then $A =X$ in this construction.

Comment: But the unicity says that whenever we have a compact set $C$ such that for some point $w \in C$, we have $A:= C\setminus \{w\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$ ,then $C$ is homeomorphic to the $X^\ast$ we are now constructing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that any such compactification exists, you can define the underlying set of $ X^*$ as $ X\cup \{\omega \}$ for any $\omega\not\in X $ and then define a suitable topology on that set. To prove that this particular construction satisfies the properties stated in the theorem you will show that $ X $ is homeomorphic to the set $ A:=X\subset X^*$ (equipped with the subspace topology).

In short: What Schubert says is technically not true for any realization of $ X^*$! But it is true, by definition, for the obvious construction of a possible realization of $ X^*$.  Also it is morally true for any realization of $ X^*$ since being homeomorphic to a subset is just as good as being that subset for all topological purposes

(Since I do not have the book I cannot judge whether Schubert actually claims that the equality holds or whether it is a definition in the sense of my first paragraph)